# Contributor commits public of a private Github repo

Tags: github, repository

Is there a way to have each contributor to a private repo have their commits be public on their github account, while still having the Github repo private?

The idea is to demonstrate contributor contribution to private repos, without revealing folder structure / code of the repo itself.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/

Comment: bummer! thanks for the point in the right direction. would be a great option for those working on private repos